# How to display loading gif image until the big image have loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, loader

What am I doing wrong?It does not show the gif.
It not necessarily has to be an element to any image that is within a `div`

```
   $('#loadbig a').each(function(index,el){

       //find this link's child image element
      var img = $(this).find('img');

      //hide the image and attach the load event handler
      $(img).hide().load(function () {

            //remove the link's "loading" classname
            $(el).removeClass('loading');

            //show the loaded image
            $(img).fadeIn();
      })
});
```

css:

```
#loadbig a.loading{
    background:url(images/loading.gif) no-repeat center center;
}
```

Comment: If the images are already loaded the `load` event will not be fired

Answer (score 0):

An anchor is an inline element which has no height therefore the background image will not show.

better to show the loading gif as an image itself and hide onload

```
$('#loadbig a').each(function(index,el){

   //find this link's child image element
  var img = $(this).find('img.bigImage');
  var loading = $(this).find('img.loading');

  //hide the image and attach the load event handler
  $(img).hide().load(function () {

        //hide loading gif
        $(loading).hide();

        //show the loaded image
        $(img).fadeIn();
  })

});
```